# trying to dilate a binary image, getting a full white image instead

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing

```
public static Color[][] dilate(Color[][] array) {

    boolean white = false;
    boolean black = false;

    Color[][] copy = new Color[array.length][array[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){

            int g = array[i][j].getGreen();

            if( g>= 0 && g< 50){
                black = true;
                //System.out.println("black is true");
            } else if(g> 200 && g < 300){
                white = true;
                //System.out.println("white is true");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Nothing");
            }

            if (white == true){
                //System.out.println("who");
                for(int x = i-3; x <= i + 3; x++){
                    //int rem = k - Math.abs(i - x);
                    for(int y = j- 3; y<= j + 3; y++){
                        if (x>=0 && y>=0 && x < array.length && y < array[0].length && black == true){
                            copy[x][y] = new Color(255, 255, 255);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

So i'm trying to dilate a binary image. I take a white pixel from the Color array, and create a threshold. If within that threshold I find any any black pixel, i make it white and store those into another array. I can't figure out why my resulting image is all white.

Comment: You never reset `white` (or `black`, but you only use `white` later), so once you hit a single white pixel everything becomes `white`.